# PayPal DoCapture - Returns 10004 Invalid Transaction ID

Tags: paypal

I am trying to test an authorization/capture process, and I am using the PayPal sample site to set up the authorization.  I have it set up to use my sandbox credentials, and everything claims success.  However, when I try to perform the capture (DoCapture), I get an invalid transaction id error.  I have tried to view the pending authorization in the test account, but cannot load the My Money section of the page.

Request string:

```
METHOD=DoCapture
&USER=MyAPIUser
&PWD=MyAPIPass
&SIGNATURE=MyAPISig
&VERSION=86
TRXTYPE=D
&AUTHORIZATIONID=TransactionIdFromSetExpressCheckoutReturn
&COMPLETETYPE=NotComplete
&AMT=1.99
&NOTE=NewspaperSubscription
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have the AUTHORIZATION=TransactionIdFromSetExpressCheckoutReturn, this should be the authorization id that is returned from the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API Response, not the SetExpressCheckout API call.  The DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call is what needs to be made to complete the authorization you are placing on the funds.  Then the DoCapture would be what you would call to capture the funds.

Comment: So, I do a SetExpressCheckout, use the token and id to call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, then take THAT id over to DoCapture?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I do, apparently.  Although that causes other issues.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'that causes other issues'?

Comment: It causes issues with the business process, not the actual software implementation.  Also, I was using the wrong API, so it kind of doesn't matter.  I do appreciate the follow up, though.